# How to get number of days between two dates in java?

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

How do I get number of days between two dates in Java?

What's the best way?  Here is what I got but it's not the best:

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getWorkingDaysMap(int year, 
    int month, int day){
        int totalworkingdays=0,noofdays=0;
        String nameofday = "";
        ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> workingDaysMap = 
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> holyDayMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        noofdays = findNoOfDays(year,month,day);

        for (int i = 1; i <= noofdays; i++) {
            Date date = (new GregorianCalendar(year,month - 1, i)).getTime();
            // year,month,day
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            nameofday = f.format(date);

            String daystr="";
            String monthstr="";

            if(i<10)daystr="0";
            if(month<10)monthstr="0";

            String formatedDate = daystr+i+"/"+monthstr+month+"/"+year;

            if(!(nameofday.equals("Saturday") || nameofday.equals("Sunday"))){
                workingDaysMap.put(formatedDate,formatedDate);
                totalworkingdays++;
            }
        }

        return workingDaysMap;
    }

public static int findNoOfDays(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);
        int days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return days;
    }
```

Comment: In particular, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4549327/22656

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
final long DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

int diffInDays = (int) ((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())/ DAY_IN_MILLIS );
```

No need for external lib, and easy enough

---

Update: Just saw you want the "Dates" between too, similar method applies:

```
//assume date1 < date2

List<Date> dateList = new LinkedList<Date>();
for (long t = date1.getTime(); t < date2.getTime() ; t += DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
  dateList.add(new Date(t));
}
```

Of course, using JODA time or other lib may make your life a bit easier, though I don't see the current way difficult to implement

---

Update: Important Note!
this only works for timezone that has no daylight saving or similar adjustment, or your definition of "difference in days" actually means "difference in 24-hour unit"

Comment: Just a reminder to people using this approach, this only works for timezone that has no daylight saving or similar adjustment.

Comment: I have rolled back the answers to the original, as the edits done to this answer is adding something that isn't part of my original answer (mentioning `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());`) I think such kind of edit is better to be put as another answer instead changing existing answer of another person.

Comment: Your first comment here is really important.  This approach gives the wrong answer if `date1` occurs during Daylight Savings Time and `date2` occurs during non-Daylight time.  It is therefore wrong for any country on earth that has daylight savings.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, I would consider putting that as part of the answer to make it more obvious